# Compiled Javascript from CoffeeScript not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I use CodeKit to compile my CoffeeScript files to JS.

Just recently, I found that one of my compiled JS file from CoffeeScript in CodeKit isn't working in IE8 any more.

I've tried to dig through IE Developer Tool and found that the error was being reported in the following lines.

```
      this["default"] = function() {
        return AlertExplorer.prototype.default.apply(_this, arguments);
      };
...
...
      this["export"] = function() {
        return ExportAuth.prototype.export.apply(_this, arguments);
      };
```

I've looked at other function declarations and they all do

```
  this.functionName = function() {
  };
```

So it seems IE8 doesn't like function declarations with square brackets []? Does that even make sense?

For now, I just simply commented the above lines and it worked ok. Is this anything to do with the latest update in CoffeeScript?

Comment: How come the second form has dot and also square brackets? It might be a problem in the spacing of your coffeescript.

Comment: oops. sorry, that was my typo. edited.